# Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
void main() async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
);
final _firebaseMessaing = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
await _firebaseMessaing.requestPermission();

final fCMToken = await _firebaseMessaing.getToken();
print("This is token =========> ${fCMToken}");

runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Here I want the token but some errors occurs and the Token does not print. Not getting why I am facing this problem?

```
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

  E/flutter (17731): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
 E/flutter (17731): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
 (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
 E/flutter (17731): <asynchronous suspension>
 E/flutter (17731): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod 
 (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:522:43)
 E/flutter (17731): <asynchronous suspension>
 E/flutter (17731): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got _firebaseMessaing.RequestPermission(). This line requests notification permissions from the user. Ensure this call is a success before asking for the token. You can add a test for the permission fame using _firebaseMessaing.GetNotificationSettings() and handle cases in which permission is denied.

Comment: I posted the answer. Got the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to this. Mainly shit issue appeared because of my emulator issue. Because google services were being stopped for some issue. Reinstalling emulator and also updating emulator from SDK manager solved the issue.
Task done:

1. Reinstall Emulator
2. Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android Emulator(Download/Upgrade)